# Image uploaded through inertiajs form.post fails mime image validation in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Laravel version: 8.82.0

I am uploading an image with inertiajs by making a post request with `form.post` method. An image data is received in controller as depicted in an image below:

[image]

My simplified controller:

```
public function store(){
    
    Request()->validate([
        'thumbnail' => 'required|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg|max:2048'

        // Also tried, still fails.
        // 'thumbnail' => 'required|image|mimes:png,jpeg,jpg|max:2048'

    ]);
    
    return Redirect::route('showcases.index');

}
```

Upon ariving header content-type is `application/json`, I tried changing it to `multipart/form-data` but to no avail, image validation still fails.

The error I get is: `The thumbnail must be a file of type: png, jpeg, jpg`

Comment: I’m not familiar with inertia. Show the html for the upload. The form needs to be enctype=multipart/form-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to validate a base64 string instead of a file.
in the string format laravel validation cant validate the mime type.
so you may try to extend the validation rules and try a better way.
Inside the `AppServiceProvider`  put the custom validation(there are many other cleaner ways)

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('image64', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $type = explode('/', explode(':', substr($value, 0, strpos($value, ';')))[1])[1];
        if (in_array($type, $parameters)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    Validator::replacer('image64', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        return str_replace(':values',join(",",$parameters),$message);
    });
}
```

now you can do :

```
'thumbnail' => 'required|image64:jpeg,jpg,png'
```